# Meaning of hippie “drop out” philosophy

Tags: meaning

> Writing to the woman who would become his third wife, Hermann Hesse
>   complained: “Life for me now holds almost no pleasures any more, in
>   fact I am living in Hell.” The event that had reduced Hesse to this
>   state of near-despair was that his wife-to-be Ninon Dolbin had moved
>   some of his books without his permission. For him this was an
>   intolerable disruption of the orderly existence he believed essential
>   to a writer who had detached himself from the world. His independence
>   required that he hold all of humankind, and even his closest
>   companion, at a rigorously policed distance. Accordingly, although the
>   two of them lived under the same roof, he communicated with Ninon
>   mainly in writing. As his latest biographer, Gunnar Decker, relates:
>   Their day-to-day communication with one another was conducted by
>   “house letters”, like in a Trappist monastery, where one has to stay
>   silent most of the time and jot down essential communications to one’s
>   fellow monks on pieces of paper. This was the way Hesse managed to
>   tolerate the presence of another person in his vicinity; he had to be
>   sure he wouldn’t suddenly be spoken to. “How was it,” Decker asks,
>   “that Hesse believed himself to be ‘living in Hell’…when he had a
>   female friend who loved him more unreservedly than any before her, and
>   who placed herself entirely at the service of his needs?” As he
>   comments: “His note sounds positively hysterical.” It is a reasonable
>   judgement. Decker is a scrupulous biographer with an unrivalled
>   knowledge of his subject, and this is undoubtedly the definitive
>   account of Hesse’s life and work. It is less clear what Decker finds
>   of intrinsic interest or value in his subject. **The most striking
>   fact about Hesse is how he was embraced by the counterculture in the
>   early Sixties – a development that secured him a posthumous reputation
>   as an exponent of the hippie “drop out” philosophy and made him the
>   most widely translated 20th-century German author.**

What does **hippie drop out philosophy** mean here?

Answer (score 1):

During the 60's

> [A hippie (sometimes spelled hippy)[1][2] is a member of the counterculture of the 1960s, originally a youth movement that began in the United States during the mid-1960s and spread to other countries around the world. The word hippie came from hipster and used to describe beatniks[3] who moved into New York City's Greenwich Village and San Francisco's Haight-Ashbury district. The term hippie first found popularity in San Francisco with Herb Caen, who was a journalist for the San Francisco Chronicle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippie)

**Drop-out** is a play on words, hippies, in general, being counterculture, *dropped out of society*, also drug experimentation was very big during this period and one of the prevalent drugs was LSD which when taken is described as "***dropping acid***".